# PHP: How to store and checkboxes values and update them

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, forms, checkbox

I'm having a problem with storing and updating checkboxes values.
When I select/unselect them all it works, but when I select the last one the value is set to the first unchecked box and so on.

HTML Form:

```
echo'<input type="hidden" name="numOfRows" value="'.mysql_num_rows($query).'">';

if ($row[10]==1)
 {
  echo'<input type="checkbox" id="activateExam" name="activateExam[]" value="1" checked="checked">';
 }
else if ($row[10]==0)
 {
  echo'<input type="checkbox"  id="activateExam"  name="activateExam[]" value="0" >';
 }
echo'<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="'.$row[0].'">';
```

PHP code:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $_POST['numOfRows']; $i++)
{
if (isset($_POST['activateExam'][$i]))
{
    $activateExam = '1';
}
else
if (!isset($_POST['activateExam'][$i]))
{
    $activateExam = '0';
}

$id = $_POST['id'][$i];
echo "exam" . $activateExam . " id: " . $id;
$sql = "UPDATE `student` SET `activateExam`='" . $activateExam . "' WHERE `ID`='" . $id . "'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$query) echo "Database Error : " . $sql;
}
```

Hope you can help, thanks anyways.

Comment: where is $_POST['numOfRows']?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to copy it, it's there now.

Comment: try the given way in answer. i think you want to active them which are selected and inactive others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try it

HTML

```
if ($row[10]==1)
 {
  echo'<input type="checkbox" id="activateExam" name="activateExam[]" value="'.$row[0].'" checked="checked">';
 }
else if ($row[10]==0)
 {
  echo'<input type="checkbox"  id="activateExam"  name="activateExam[]" value="'.$row[0].'" >';
 }
```

and php

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `student` SET `activateExam`=0 ") or die(mysql_error()); // update all to 0

if(isset($_POST['activateExam']))
{
   $arr_active_exam = $_POST['activateExam'];
   if(sizeof($arr_active_exam)>0)
   {
      foreach($arr_active_exam as $id)
      {
          mysql_query("UPDATE `student` SET `activateExam`=1  WHERE id='$id' ") or die(mysql_error()); // update all to 1 which is checked 
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: you can use limit 1 if your id column is primary key. as WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1